# is there any way to plot ROC curves from weka

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, dataset, java, weka

i am using some algorithms from weka . i was willing to plot some algorithms' roc curve for comparison . Is it possible and how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the Weka explorer, go to the classify tab and train/test your algorithm.
2. The result buffer appears in the bottom left box under the section labeled "result list"
3. Right click the result buffer and click visualize threshold curve, then select the class you want to analyze
4. to save the ROC curve as an image, hold shift + alt and left click on the graph